# Visualization a set of angles

Tags: python, graph, coordinates

I have an array of angles and i want to put them on Cartesian graph as lines
I look for an conversion degree to (x,y) but couldn't pick a simple and good one
What's the best way to do it.

Comment: This is a math question, not python. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

angles = [0, np.pi/4, np.pi/2, np.pi]

xlist = [np.cos(ang) for ang in angles]
ylist = [np.sin(ang) for ang in angles]

for x, y in zip(xlist, ylist):
  plt.plot([0,x],[0,y])
plt.show()
```

If you need to plot lines, you need at least two points. I am assuming that the first one can be the origin for your problem. The second one can be any point that gives you the desired angle. So, i choose a radius of 1.

The coordinates of a point that is 1 unit far from the origin are `x = cos(angle)` and `y = sin(angle)`.

Then, all you need is to plot a line conecting (0,0) to (x,y) for each angle, which you can do by using matplotlib and a `for` loop.